# Interaction between the group and child items of ExpandableListView?

Tags: android, android-view, expandablelistview

I want to achieve a functionality where the groupView of the ExpandableListView consists of a Switch.

Depending on the state of this switch, the child view needs to change accordingly.

For demo purpose, I've put the switch in the childView to explain my desired functionality.

If switchState is not Selected (default state), then this view
[image]

Else if selected then, this view

[image]

My question is, how do I interact with the getChildView method for it to respond by displaying appropriate views according to the state change of the Switch in the getGroupView method?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.